# Brown out implementation in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver, interrupt-handling

I have embedded data logger in which data comes from external sensors which are stored temporarily in a file (`tmpfs`) and are backed up into another file on flash. How can i implement a brown out handler by which i can save the data from being lost ?

Comment: I don't understand.  Do you want to be safe against sudden power loss (hardware shuts down without time to react)?  Then of course you need to write to a permanent store each time, and make sure you flush all buffers.  Or do you want something else?

Comment: Thanks Alfe :)

Permanent storage is flash based so writing to it each time is questionable. There is an external PMIC connected with main SOC through I2C which gives an interrupt upon power loss with a capacitor bank that gives few msec before black out. I want to use this interrupt to back up data from ram based file to permanent storage.

Comment: Then maybe you ask that on superuser instead of stackoverflow.  It seems to be more an admin question than a programming question as you mainly want to know how to react on that power-loss signal your hardware provides.

Comment: Are you asking _what to do_ when this signal is received, or _how to receive_ the signal?

Comment: I want to save the data after the signal is recieved. I want to know the best way to do it in an Embedded Linux System.

Comment: @user3090306 The best way is to not handle it at this layer. If you get a brown-out signal, it's normally too late to safely try to store something and ensure consistency. You would rather need to periodically "back up" your tmpfs files to permanent storage in a safe manner, (fsync()/fdatasync() might help you), and preferably to a journaled filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

Having a brown-out handler in a system is just matter of having Linux kernel device driver implementation. For such a task, the best would be to consult the [LDD](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/) book.

But if you ask me, more important question is if it would really help you to save the data? Because brown-out is just that: a brown-out :) I would not bet you will have enough time to save all of the data (depends on a data size, RAM/flash R/W speed, internal priority handling of kernel, maybe some other timings as well, etc.).

Generally, such a problem is tackled with usage of journaling file systems, which prevent the system from having data **corrupted** (but cannot prevent the data loss). More info on such systems: [Journaling File System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journaling_file_system)